# Is there any good XY plot tools using latex

Tags: graphics, plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparison of plotting packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15763/comparison-of-plotting-packages)

Let us say I have x-axis data and the corresponding y-axis data. I was wondering if latex had any graphing abilities. I might want to put axis labels, put some title. Some times, there will be multiple y-axis data, as I might be comparing functions for same x-axis values. In that case, I will need to label each function curve with different marker (symbol).

Any graphical tool which does this is more than welcome but I don't mind taking the extra effort of learning some latex library if thats what it takes ( I learned tikz for drawing pictures, and I find it amazing!!).

Between, matlab does a good job for me now. But, I would like to get that "everything in my hands" feel when one uses latex to create docs.

Comment: You can start looking at the highest voted `pgfplots` questions here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots?sort=votes&pagesize=50 and here is the manual: [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots)

Comment: [PGFPlots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: See: [Comparison of plotting packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15763/comparison-of-plotting-packages). I suggest closing as a duplicate - we could still add to the other question.